# create a smart contract that holds and sends funds to set wallets

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, ether

Hi im new to smart contracts and trying to create a contract that stores and splits the funds between founders is this anywhere near close or can anyone help me please. Thank you

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.7.4;

import './Ownable.sol';

interface wallet {

    function getCut(address _from, address _to, uint _value) external returns(bool success);

    function splitFoundersCut(uint _amount, address Ceo, address Cfo, address Cto) external returns(bool success);
}

interface ERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns(uint supply);

    function balanceOf(address _owner) external view returns(uint balance);

    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) external returns(bool success);

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) external returns(bool success);

    function approve(address _spender, uint _value) external returns(bool success);

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) external view returns(uint remaining);

    function decimals() external view returns(uint digits);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint _value);

    function deposit() external payable;

    function withdraw(uint256 wad) external;
}

contract FoundersWallet is Ownable {

    address payable Ceo = 0x471F9361ec8Fc947d371B95e5a5f5820C7A42A1B;
    address payable Cto = 0x471F9361ec8Fc947d371B95e5a5f5820C7A42A1B;
    address payable Cfo = 0x471F9361ec8Fc947d371B95e5a5f5820C7A42A1B;

    uint256 amount = address(this).balance;

    function withdraw() internal returns(bool) {

        if(amount > 0) {
            Ceo.transfer((amount / 40));
            Cto.transfer((amount / 40));
            Cfo.transfer((amount / 20));
        }

        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is assigning the value of `uint256 amount` only when the contract is created, and not updating it when the balance changes. Which would result in having the value of `amount` always `0`.

*Note: I'm not counting for edge cases like the contract address already having ETH value before the contract is deployed, or sending ETH to your contract using `selfdestruct()`. These are valid cases, but out of scope for this question.*

The `withdraw()` function is expected to return boolean. But when you don't return any value, the caller may interpret it as `false`. So I'd advise to `return true` if the transfer was successful.

Also, you might want to be able to call the `withdraw()` function externally, so mark it as `external` instead of `internal`. *But this depends on your use case and maybe you're already calling it internally from another function that is not shown in your question.*

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.4;

contract FoundersWallet is Ownable {

    address payable Ceo = 0x471F9361ec8Fc947d371B95e5a5f5820C7A42A1B;
    address payable Cto = 0x471F9361ec8Fc947d371B95e5a5f5820C7A42A1B;
    address payable Cfo = 0x471F9361ec8Fc947d371B95e5a5f5820C7A42A1B;

    function withdraw() external returns(bool) { // visibility `external`
        // moved the `amount` here so that it's recalculated on each function call
        uint256 amount = address(this).balance;

        if(amount > 0) {
            Ceo.transfer((amount / 40));
            Cto.transfer((amount / 40));
            Cfo.transfer((amount / 20));
            
            return true; // added the return value
        }
        
        // don't need the `else` because of the early return
        return false;
    }
}
```